# Python pandas reading table data but commas is removed

Tags: python, pandas, request

how do I have the original data for column "Winning No". How to have the comma not removed?

Result should be 1,45,13,12,13 instead of 145131213

Here my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 0
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000

url = 'https://en.lottolyzer.com/history/singapore/toto'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)



df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Comment: why would pass directly  received request to read_html ,it should  be converted in html format like html.fromstring(html)

Comment: Hi Ahmed, so how should correct it? thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the `read_html` documentation I found out that the parameters `decimal` and `thousands` could be helpful in these cases, but they do not work in this specific one. With that being said, I propose a customized solution which makes use also of the `BeautifulSoup` library in order to parse the HTML result in an easier way.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.lottolyzer.com/history/singapore/toto'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Extract the initial DataFrame from the HTML table.
# Note that read_html returns a list of DataFrames (one for each table retrieved from the HTML), 
# so we need to select the first element (in the webpage there is only one table).
df_initial = pd.read_html(html)[0]

# Find the HTML table containing the winning numbers
table = soup.find('table', class_='responsive-table')

# Extract the "Winning No" column and add commas
# The last row of this block is used to preserve the format of the original HTML table,
# which reports the column label also into the last line.
winning_no = table.find_all('td', class_='sum-p1')[1::3]
winning_no = [num.text for num in winning_no]
winning_no.append(winning_no.pop(0))

# Create a DataFrame with the "Winning No" column
df = pd.DataFrame({'Winning No.': [num for num in winning_no]})

# Replacing the "Winning No" column in the initial DataFrame with the new parsed column.
df_initial['Winning No.'] = df['Winning No.']
print(df_initial)
```

TL;DR:

the line `winning_no = table.find_all('td', class_='sum-p1')[1::3]` finds all the table rows with class `sum-p1` which by inspecting the results give this output:

```
    <td class="sum-p1">Date</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">Winning No.</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">Addl No.</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">2023-05-08</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">1,3,6,11,23,34</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">39</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">2023-05-04</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">16,21,25,28,37,44</td>, 
    <td class="sum-p1">24</td>, 
    ...
]
```

As you can see the `Winning No.` elements starts from the element of index 1 of this array and are reachable by accessing the array starting from that index to the end with step 3 ([1::3]).

This line instead `winning_no.append(winning_no.pop(0))` is used to remove the Header, i.e. the string `Winning No.` from the head of the list and put it in the last position. In this way when in the next step we'll create back the dataframe we will preserve the original structure of the table, having the label of the column both on the top of the table and in its last row.

Comment: Hi Paolo, thks could you explain this : df_initial = pd.read_html(html)[0] what does the [0] do?can it be any number beside 0?

Comment: Also this: winning_no = table.find_all('td', class_='sum-p1')[1::3]

Comment: winning_no = [num.text for num in winning_no]
winning_no.append(winning_no.pop(0))

Comment: Hi, `df_initial = pd.read_html(html)[0]` is used to extract a dataframe object from the list of dataframes that the command `read_html` returns (note that from the [method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) we can see that it returns always a list of dataframes, regardless the fact that the HTML page may contain only one single table, like in this case. So with that command I am extracting the `pandas.DataFrame` object corresponding to the table which you can find at the URL you posted.

Comment: This line `winning_no = table.find_all('td', class_='sum-p1')[1::3]` has been produced after inspecting the content of the table. By printing the variable table from the code above you can see that the label Winning No. and its corresponding values are present in the HTML document with td tags whose class is sum-p1 (you have also sum-p2 in the table for example which refers to other elements of the table). As said in the answer posted, the method find_all returns an array of td elements with class sum-p1 retrieved from the HTML.

Comment: Then from the list we pick only those values which are related to the Winning No. column. By inspecting the content of the list, I found out that the first element of interest is the label of the column Winning No. which is the element of index 1. All the values which populates the column are all those elements in the list which begin at index 1 and are fetched by making a step of 3 indices each time (so the element of index 1 is the label, the element with index 4 is the content of the first cell of that column, the element with index 7 is the content of the second cell, and so on).

Comment: Before applying this last line `winning_no = [num.text for num in winning_no] winning_no.append(winning_no.pop(0))`, the situation inside the variable `winning_no` is the following: `winning_no = ["Winning No.', '1,3,6,11,23,34', .... ]`. We would like to have `winning_no = [ '1,3,6,11,23,34', ..., 'Winning No.' ]` in order to reproduce the format of the original (ill-defined) table we have fetched. The command does exactly this passage, i.e. it removes the label 'Winning No.' from the first position of the list and push it back in the last position.

Comment: Many thks Paolo I will try to understand it

Comment: Sorry one more question where does this num.text come from? I know FOR loop method but yours is a bit diff it start with num.text then for loop what does num.text at the beginning? Thks

Comment: It is a python feature called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I think I am not able to explain the concept better than the python documentation.

Comment: Morning Paolo thks for the link appreciated